# Using helper methods like html_escape in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-escape

I am trying to see what is going wrong with my encoding of variables in my view. So I fire up rails console and try to do

```
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.11)
irb(main):001:0> html_escape({:a=>1, :b=>"my str"})
NoMethodError: undefined method `html_escape' for main:Object
```

How do I use h or html_escape in rails console?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you call it through `helper`.  some methods are private so you may need to use send to call them

```
helper.send(:html_escape, '123')
helper.pluralize 3, 'user'
```

Comment: looks like I getting a few of those today.

Answer (score 12):

Easy to solve. html_escape is defined in ERB::Util so simply write:

```
include ERB::Util
```

in your console prior to the first use of html_escape

Comment: any idea what the html_escape helper method does? (noob trying to learn.)

Comment: It calls CGI.escapeHTML with provided string

Answer (score 0):

```
> helper.send(:html_escape, '{ a: 1, b: "my str" }')
"{ a: 1, b: &quot;my str&quot; }"
```

Comment: you should check the answers as well, if something is already answered, then you do not need to write the same answer again.